# Why is that after deleting an index in logstash, Kibana still displays it?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have 2 indexes `movie_indexer` and `trial_indexer`.

I used the following command to delete movie_indexer:

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/movie_indexer/"
```

Then i reran Kibana. It still showed the index and its values.

When i used

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/.kibana"
```

after that `trial_indexer` was missing.

Note: After using latter command, i could create the index pattern for `trial_indexer` but not for movie_indexer.

I want to delete the specific index w/o the need to recreate an index pattern for undeleted indexes. How can i do that? (i'm using windows)

Comment: Do you have an ongoing process that is indexing data in real-time in the `movie_indexer` index? If so, is it possible that just after you deleted the index, new data came in and the `movie_indexer` index was recreated?

Comment: There is no real time data being used. Oh btw the data gets deleted. Kibana shows no results available for the deleted index. But why does the index name still show up in kibana?

Comment: Oh, ok, then that's normal, it's simply because you've set up an index pattern within Kibana and that configuration gets saved inside Kibana (inside the `.kibana` index). That's useful when preparing a Kibana setup in DEV/STAGE in order to later deploy that to production, for instance. Also for sharing your Kibana setup with other people.

Comment: Thanks! So i have to manually delete the index pattern in kibana then. There is no way i can delete both the data and the index pattern for a specific index at once?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's normal because Kibana will store an index pattern and the associated field settings from the mapping inside his own index called `.kibana`.

If you want to delete the `movie_indexer` index (containing the data) **and** the associated index pattern in Kibana (containing the Kibana settings for that index), you can do so by issuing two queries, namely the one you already did to delete the data

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/movie_indexer/"
```

and another one to delete the index pattern in Kibana, where `pattern_name` is the name you gave to the index pattern you wish to delete (by default it's the same name as your index, i.e. `movie_indexer`)

```
curl -XDELETE "http://localhost:9200/.kibana/index-pattern/pattern_name"
```

Note that you can also delete the index pattern directly in Kibana by going into Settings > Indices, then picking the index pattern you want and clicking on the "remove index pattern" button